# Merging files in Bash

Tags: file, bash, shell

I had this homework assignment:

1. Create on the desktop a folder with your name.
2. Copy from your account `XYZ@xyz.com` two files, `"plik1.pdp"` and `"plik2.pdb"`.
3. Combine them to make a new file, `"plik3.pdb"`, but they have to be in special order. The second file should be first, and then the first one.
4. Write down from the connected/combined `"plik3.pdb"` lines with "`CA`" to the new file `"plik4.pdb"`.
5. In this new file, change the lines 1-240 from `"1.00"` to `"0.00"`.

The following code is my solution:

```
cd Desktop
mkdir "name"
cd "name"
scp XYZ@xyz.com:/home/XYZ plik[12].pdb
cat plik2.pdb plik1.pdb > plik3.pdb
grep 'CA' plik3 > plik4
sed -i -n 1,240p -e 's/1\.00/0\.00' plik4
```

Is it ok? Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: `Is it ok?` Did you check whether it works as expected?

Comment: What is XYZ? Is it not for real? I mean, just an example? In those times of Alphabet and https://xyz.xyz/, I think it is a reasonable doubt.

Answer (score 1):

Overall it is close, but it won't work.  Given that it's a homework assignment, you would possibly get points for trying, but if you ever intend to use bash scripting after school (and you should; it's very useful) do yourself a favor and set up a Linux test environment on your personal computer to play around with.

Only two things wrong that I see (though I didn't test it).  In order of simplicity:

1. You stopped including the filename extensions in your last two commands.  `plik3.pdp` and `plik3` refer to two different files; extensions are not considered in any special way in Linux and are simply part of the filename.
2. Your `scp` command is wrong.  I don't *think* it will do anything (just throw an error), but if it does anything it definitely won't be what you expect.

Try `scp XYZ@xyz.com:/home/XYZ/plik{1,2}.pdb ./`

Note the added slash in the source name, and the inclusion of a target directory `./`, which refers to the current working directory (in this case, `Desktop/name`).

By the way, the shell will expand the above to `scp XYZ@xyz.com:/home/XYZ/plik1.pdb XYZ@xyz.com:/home/XYZ/plik2.pdb ./`  Which gives you a hint on syntax if you need to copy multiple files that don't have the first part of the name in common.

Comment: If you install vagrant and virtualbox, which are free and easily available for Mac, Windows and Linux, you can very easily set up a virtual machine running Linux.

Comment: The OP also forgot the final `/` in the sed `s///` command.